# How to pass a generic enum to a method and set it to a dynamic object inside the method

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, enums

I have roughly 20+ enums that are all the same, but coming from different web service libraries, so when used they all need they're fully namespaced reference like this below

1. WebServices_Production_TrustOnline_ARM.yesnounspecified
2. WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.yesnounspecified
3. WebServices_Production_TrustOnline_BW.yesnounspecified
4. WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_BW.yesnounspecified
5. etc
6. etc up to 20+

Where each enum is like this below

```
public enum yesnounspecified
{
    unspecified,
    yes,
    no,
}
```

In my method I set all the values of a dynamic object, also from each of the different web services
and I need to be able to set the enum to (yes/no) but not sure how to pass it in and use it

```
ex.

MyMethod("something", new WebServices_Production_TrustOnline_ARM.objectToFill());


public void MyMethod(string otherParam, dynamic someObject) {

    // 'cigarettes' is a 'yesnospecified' enum
    someObject.cigarettes = // need to set the enum value (yes/no) here but not sure how to pass it in and set it

}
```

Comment: Do they all have the same integer values? `(yesnounspecified)(int)x;`

Comment: yes, I believe so as none of them actually specify any int values. They are in the web service file just as I have shown in my example, with just the names, no int values specified

Comment: @user1186050 you want to set `someObject.cigarettes = yes/no` from Enum ...right? correct me if am wrong

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using reflection**

```
public void MyMethod(string otherParam, object someObject) 
{
    var prop = someObject.GetType().GetProperty("cigarettes");
    var enumType = prop.PropertyType;
    prop.SetValue(someObject, Enum.Parse(enumType, "yes"), null);
}
```

This gets the information about the "cigarettes" property using reflection, including the enum type. `Enum.Parse(enumType, string)` or `Enum.ToObject(enumType, intValue)` can then be used to construct a value of this type. `SetValue` writes the constructed value to the property.

**Using generics**

An alternative - if the value is fixed - would be to make the method generic and pass the enum value to the method:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(string otherParam, dynamic someObject, T value) 
{
    someObject.cigarettes = value;
}
```

Call: `MyMethod("x", obj, yesnounspecified.yes);`

Comment: And this will actually extract the enum from the dynamic object? So that I can use it?

Comment: Yes, it will do. Performance will not be the best, so if you call this method very often it would be better to write 20+ variants of it.

Comment: no it only gets called a couple times a week, but wouldn't be eaier to just pass in some kind of generic? I'm not that experienced with generics but it seems like that would be the best solution, but I don't know how it would be done!

Comment: like what if I pass it in as a dynamic?

Comment: Added an alternative to my answer.

Comment: you're alternative won't work because I'm calulating the value (yes/no) inside the method. Your solution passes in the calculated value.

Comment: You could then pass a `Func<whatever, T>` instead of a `T`. But I would go for reflection.

Comment: couldn't I just pass in another dynamic (enum) ? Isn't a dynamic reflection?

Comment: I think I want to pass in "new WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.yesnounspecified()" so in the method I can use logic to set the 'cigarettes' with the dynamic parameter like 'dynamic yesNoUnspecified' and then use it like 'yesNoUnspecified.yes' or 'yesNoUnspecified.no'